# MVC в IOS при наличии storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mvc, шаблоны-проектирования

Привет всем. Задался вопросом о паттерне MVC. Конкретно о самом паттерне все ясно. Но хотелось бы понять, как в MVC запихать storyboard. Это как прослойка view или одновременно View и Controller? Не ясно, ведь в ней уже можно располагать и размечать вьюхи, тогда нужно ли вообще View прослойка? Короч, расскажите, если кто писал используя MVC вместе со storyboard
Спасибо)

Comment: ну мое мнение такое : в большенстве случаев storyboard может быть view, с другой стороны вью связан с контроллером потому в некоторых случаях стоит рассматривать storyboard + viewController = view это позволит сделать большое количество кода более читаемым и такая тенденция началась, как мне кажется, от того что не все понимают: MVC - не значит что на каждый екран должно быть три файла, а многи так делают и в итоге получаем  massive view controller

Answer (score 1):

IB элементы относятся к интерфейсу, то есть View. Притом слово Controller в ViewController не обязательно означает Controller из MVC, он может содержать логику приложения, но если это очень большое количество кода, лучше создавать отдельный объект(ы).
 Есть много адептов и противников разных архитектурных паттернов. Старайтесь использовать здравый смысл, и не раздувать обьекты, и не создавать кучу мелких. В Swift очень удобно, что в одном файле вы можете разместить несколько классов или разбить большой класс на файлы с extentions. В общем то код должен получиться понятным и удобным для изменения и масштабирования.

Comment: Хорошее объяснение, но все еще не понятно. Например, если у меня есть stroryBoard с обычном viewController - ом, и я на него положил, например, две вьюхи и кнопку назад, то нужно ли для него создавать файл вью, а если да, то что там например может быть. Вот например легко понимается если у меня есть tableView, то в файлах view у меня будут его cell. А вот с другими примерами не ясно(

Comment: что значит "создавать для него файл вью"?  у каждого UIViewController есть свойство view, которое вы видите в IB.

Comment: Да, но ведь это уже не получается MVC, вы грубо говоря все делаете во viewController файле.

Comment: я делаю в разных местах, разные вещи. В Свифте мы делаем что то в классах а не в файлах.

Comment: ну классы выносят в файлы, как правило, поэтому так и говорю)

Comment: как я писал в ответе в Swift классы никак не зависят от файлов и наоборот, может быть один класс разбит на несколько файлов, а может один файл содержать несколько классов

Answer (score 1):

По этой теме уже написано Очень и очень много статей. Главная проблема что [ожидания](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не совпадают с реальностью:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Изображение взято из [статьи на habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/company/badoo/blog/281162/). Ознакомьтесь, если еще не добрались.)

И в данном случае главное четко отделить Model.

Также необходимо понять, что слой View - это не просто один файлик UIView, а Controller - не есть UIViewController. Это именно слои. Абстрактные. И в контексте iOS к View относится и Stroyboards с их содержимым (при желании некоторые сценарии в storyboard конечно можно отнести к Controller), и Xibs, и созданные программно. А в некоторых т.н. архитектурах даже UIViewController относят к View слою (MVP, MVVM...).

Comment: Теперь начинаю доезжать, но не понятно главное, как красиво разделить код. К примеру, у меня есть Stroyboard, не нем лежит две UIVIew, скажем, красная и синяя. Я хочу по нажатию кнопки менять цвет этих вьюх. Так вот, получается что мне нужно каждую вью линкануть в класс, привязанный к Stroyboard(ViewController), и там производить все эти махинации. А если вопрос не тупо в смене цвета, а масштабнее. Вот и вопрос, как сделать красиво, и верно ли делать такие действия в классе controller?

Comment: @AndrewGurew если масштабнее - выносите это "масштабнее" в Model.